# How to check php code for psr 2 validation in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, laravel-5, coding-style, psr-2

Is there any Plugin in Netbeans for checking PSR2 Violation and fix the same.

I tried adding `php-cs-fixer.phar` in `Netbeans > Options > php >  frameworks and tools > PHP CS Fixer`.Then click on Fix option PHP CS Fixer.This option can be seen by right clicking on `filename.php` in netbeans.

This fix only removes extra spaces from code but not fixing camel cases.

Is there any other option to fix [psr-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Comment: For laravel : https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer